# Serve files using Rack TryStatic directly?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rack, middleman

I'm using Middleman to create a static site.

Middleman generates static html files into `./build` directory.

Here's the config I'm currently using:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'middleman'
require 'rack/contrib/try_static'

use Rack::TryStatic, :root => "build", :urls => %w[/], :try => ['.html']

run Middleman::Application.server
```

So Middleman is serving the static files right now. How can I make `Rack::TryStatic` handle the requests directly?

I tried to make it something like

```
run Rack::TryStatic, :root => "build", :urls => %w[/], :try => ['.html']
```

But it doesn't work is run only accepts 1 argument. And `Rack::TryStatic` requires 2 arguments, `app` and `options` to initialize, and I don't have any `app`.

How can I do this?

(And if it matters, I'm deploying to Heroku)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you’ve noticed, a Rack middleware component such as `Rack::TryStatic` needs another app to pass requests onto. You could create a simple one to use that for example just returned a 404 response, such as:

```
app = lambda {|env| [404, {'Content-type' => 'text/plain'}, ['Not found']
run Rack::TryStatic.new app, :root => "build", :urls => %w[/], :try => ['.html']
```

or equivalently:

```
use Rack::TryStatic, :root => "build", :urls => %w[/], :try => ['.html']
run lambda {|env| [404, {'Content-type' => 'text/plain'}, ['Not found']]}
```

If you have your own 404 file, you could use rack-contrib’s [`Rack::NotFound`](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/not_found.rb) instead of a custom end point of your own:

```
use Rack::TryStatic, :root => "build", :urls => %w[/], :try => ['.html']
run Rack::NotFound.new('path/to/your/404.html')
```

If you weren’t using the `:try` array of file extensions to try and serve, you could use [`Rack::File`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/file.rb) directly. Internally, `Rack::TryStatic` uses [`Rack::Static`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/static.rb), which in turn uses `Rack::File`. Unlike `TryStatic` and `Static`, `Rack::File` is a Rack application in its own right, and so doesn’t need a separate app to pass requests to. Your `config.ru` would then simply be:

```
run Rack::File.new './build'
```

although this wouldn’t allow for “bare” requests to be served with the corresponding `.html` file — all requests would need to specify the whole file name.